# How do I add a custom button to my "edit" list? ( edit.php?post_type= ) beside "Add New"

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, customization, wp-admin, admin-ui

I have a custom post type for a plugin I'm creating and the label for the "add an item" type of button (at the top of the list page) needs a partner-button that says "*import*" and one that says "*export*" so that I can (after a brief confirmation dialogue) allow my client to push and pull the records with a JSON file that is **already all set up**; I just need them to be able to trigger it and I can't figure out how to add buttons to the list page.

[image: A screenshot of the button on the edit list]

So I need to add "Import" and "Export" after the "Add an Entry" button.

***Any help is greatly appreciated.***

Comment: Did you find the solution? Because I have the same problem

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to get it done but I am not very happy with this procedure. Please add your answer if you find better way. Mean while, this might be of help.

```
add_action('admin_head-edit.php','addCustomImportButton'));
```

I only need this on edit page, so I am using admin_head-edit.php action, but you can use admin_head or some other (not very specific requirement)

```
/**
 * Adds "Import" button on module list page
 */
public function addCustomImportButton()
{
    global $current_screen;

    // Not our post type, exit earlier
    // You can remove this if condition if you don't have any specific post type to restrict to. 
    if ('module' != $current_screen->post_type) {
        return;
    }

    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready( function($)
            {
                jQuery(jQuery(".wrap h2")[0]).append("<a  id='aspose_doc_popup' class='add-new-h2'>Import</a>");
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I scraped the WordPress source code to find this solution that is in pure PHP and has been available since WordPress 4.4.

You can use the action "manage_posts_extra_tablenav" to insert whatever you want before and after the table.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_posts_extra_tablenav/

This is an example:

```php
add_action('manage_posts_extra_tablenav', function($which) {
    if (get_current_screen()->post_type !== 'ticket'){
        return;
    }
    echo '<div class="actions alignleft"><button>Custom button</button></div>';
});
```

[image]

Comment: THIS is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't add button next to the "Add new" without injecting it with javascript.
The closest hook is edit_form_top to add your button below the title line like this:

[image]

In my sample I've added a button to my custom post type "Event":

```
add_action('edit_form_top', 'add_custom_button');

function add_custom_button($id){
    if ($post->post_type != 'event') return false;
    echo('<button>Custom button</button>');
}
```